# How in Visual Basics change characters in a string for example (1 to 0) and (0 to 1)?

Tags: vb.net, binary, flip

How in Visual Basics change characters in a string for example (1 to 0)
and (0 to 1) without the problem of changing them first to all to 0 and then all to 1, i want to get a result for example like that "00110010101101001010" to "11001101010010110101" (to flip it)

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this yourself?

Comment: @PeterBrittain it's not the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an intermediate value.

```
Change all 0 -> 2
Change all 1 -> 0
Change all 2 -> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
    Dim text = "00110010101101001010"
    Dim flipped = New String(text.Select(Function(c) If(c = "0"c, "1"c, "0"c)).ToArray())
```

That gives me:

```
11001101010010110101
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert the string to a character array iterate over each character individually; then build a new string from the modified array (or overwrite the original):

```
    Dim data As String = "00110010101101001010"
    Dim arr() As Char = data.ToCharArray
    For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
        arr(i) = If(arr(i) = "1", "0", "1")
    Next
    Dim data2 As New String(arr)
    Debug.Print(data)
    Debug.Print(data2)
```